# How to correctly create a Custom Renderer for StackLayout in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a `StackLayout` custom renderer, and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers), the base renderer is a `ViewRenderer`.

So I ended up with this for iOS:

```cs
public class MyCustomStackLayout : StackLayout { }

public class MyCustomStackLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyCustomStackLayout, UIView> 
{   
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ExportableStackLayout> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // some customizations here that don't mess with BackgroundColor at all
            // removing all customizations doesn't fix the issue either.
        }
}
```

And I'm using it like this in my XAML:

```xml
<custom:MyCustomStackLayout BackgroundColor="Green">
</custom:MyCustomStackLayout>
```

Almost everything is working fine, the renderer is registered correctly and it behaves like a `StackLayout`, even allowing for `Orientation` to change, but for some reason the `BackgroundColor` set in my `MyCustomStackLayout`, is ignored, so it is always transparent.

I couldn't find exactly where in the codebase the Renderer for the original `StackLayout` is registered, as it is not registered in the [AssemblyInfo](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/190dda803621cb61a2d93834cdbddae2bac3c777/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs) with the other renderers, so I'm not 100% sure I'm doing the right thing here.

Is there something I'm missing that is making the `BackgroundColor` get ignored? Am I using the correct Renderer for `StackLayout`? Does anybody know where exactly it gets registered?

Update: I do know how to implement the BackgroundColor, I'm actually interested in understanding why it *doesn't* work in the first place. Since I'm using the same renderer from the original StackLayout, which [already implements this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/ViewRenderer.cs#L193).

Answer (score 2):

It seems a design issue of ViewRenderer . You could add the following code in the renderer .

```
protected override void SetBackgroundColor(Color color)
{
    base.SetBackgroundColor(color);

    if (NativeView == null)
        return;

    if (color != Color.Default)
        NativeView.BackgroundColor = color.ToUIColor();
}
```

Comment: My point is that I shouldn't have to do that, since I'm theoretically using the same renderer from the original StackLayout

Comment: So what did you want to do ?

Comment: I expect the custom renderer to work as the default StackLayout renderer: respecting the BackgroundColor set in my XAML.

Comment: I updated the question with the XAML I'm using to make it more clear.

Comment: You're missing my point: I do know how to fix the problem, my question is why it doesn't work in the first place, since I'm inheriting from the original StackLayout renderer which already has this behavior implemented. As it can be seen here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/ViewRenderer.cs#L193

Comment: As I said , this seems a issue of XF , I will post it on github of Xamarin.Forms  .

Comment: If you do please share the Issue here